# Using ImageView for panoramic view

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview

Is it possible to use ImageView to draw a panoramic picture? I.E. When you scroll to the end of the right edge of a panoramic picture, it should start showing the left edge of the picture. I know there is a panoramicgl project for android, but I was thinking of doing this manually. Right now, I have scrolling and zooming using Android's matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible, but you need to have a scrollview too.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to subclass ImageView and implement onTouchEvent() to listen to userinput that will modify the current focal point. If the focal point is moved, redraw the picture to an offscreenbitmap, e.g. with matrix.postTranslate(deltaX,deltaY), and redraw the portion of the image that has been shifted out of bounds on the opposite side.